# Ajax response wrapped in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Doing an ajax request, i expect the response to be an object, but the response is an object wrapped in ”jQuery()”. How do I get my object so I can parse it?
My ajax request:

```
$.ajax({type: 'GET', url: url, success: function(result) { ... });
```

My response looks like this:

```
jQuery({"html":{”div1”:"","div2”:"<div>My result div</div>"}});
```

Comment: i suggest you fix the response from your url page

Comment: What does your ajax file returns?

Comment: You seem to be returning JSONP with a callback function named `jQuery`, which seems like a horrible idea, as that function will have a conflict with the actual jQuery function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify dataType in ajax. Your request should look like this $.ajax({type: 'GET', dataType: 'JSON', url: url, success: function(result) { ... });

Refer to jquery documentation for more info: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/